# Found Unit but required Double

Tags: scala

```html
def Perm_Function(xs: List[(Int,Int)], Dimensions: Int): Double = {
    var sum=0.0
for(i <- 1 to Dimensions)
{
sum=sum+(Perm_help(xs,i))
}
}
```

i wrote above code but it is giving error:
found:Unit
required:Double
can somebody please help.
whats wrong over there?

Comment: What do you return? What is the return value of a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not returning anything, just changing the value of `sum` variable

```
def Perm_Function(xs: List[(Int,Int)], Dimensions: Int): Double = {

var sum=0.0
for(i <- 1 to Dimensions) {
  sum=sum+(Perm_help(xs,i))
}

sum // return sum

}
```

a more idiomatic approach would be to write your code as:

```
def permFunction(xs: List[(Int,Int)], Dimensions: Int): Double = {
  (1 to dimensions).map(dim => permHelp(xs,dim)).sum
}
```